# NGINX - How to hide IP on netstat

Tags: nginx, proxy

I leave my doubt here so that eventually people with more knowledge about Nginx can help me.

I have an application that uses port 2083, working as follows:

User -> Server where Nginx Proxy is hosted (Machine 1) -> Real IP of the application (Machine 2).

My goal is that the user when connecting (after Nginx redirection) on machine 2 (where the application is hosted) cannot be able to view the real machine's IP (in order to prevent any DDoS attacks).

It turns out that after connecting to the application and opening the command prompt(cmd), typing netstat -n displays the real IP address of the machine (which I want to hide).

Would it be possible to do this (hide real IP) using Nginx itself? All redirects are working perfectly, I just want to hide the IP address of the machine where the application is hosted.

I took a read about the IPTables function "MASQUERADING", tried both machines and it didn't work. The netstat IP address is still displayed. I have also tested the parameter "proxy_bind $ remote_addr transparent;" from Nginx, without success.

my code in nginx.conf:

```
    server {
    listen 2083;
    proxy_pass IP_MYSERVER: 2083;
    }
}
```

Comment: UP. Its possible? Hide ip showing on netstat?